# How does this pointer aliasing work?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, type-punning

https://kukuruku.co/post/i-do-not-know-c/

Problem #7:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int *i, long *l)
{
  printf("1. v=%ld\n", *l); /* (1) */
  *i = 11;                  /* (2) */
  printf("2. v=%ld\n", *l); /* (3) */
}
int main()
{
  long a = 10;
  f((int *) &a, &a);
  printf("3. v=%ld\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Output on two different compilers on a little endian system is:

```
1. v=10    2. v=11    3. v=11
1. v=10    2. v=10    3. v=11
```

How is the second result possible ? I didn't quite get how the explanation that explains the result by referring to strict aliasing. Does the compiler ignore the line (2) totally ?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. *Upd:* BTW, looked at the article, and it *is* about undefined behavior. Have you read that?

Comment: My guess is your Compiler 2 (what ever it might be) is probably doing some `premature optimization`

Comment: @Zakir Compilers are not susceptible to *premature* optimization....

Comment: @Zakir What do you mean by "_premature optimization_"?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing):

> In C or C++, as mandated by the strict aliasing rule, **pointer
>   arguments in a function are assumed to not alias if they point to**
>   **fundamentally different types, except for char* and void*, which may
>   alias to any other type**. Some compilers allow the strict aliasing rule
>   to be turned off, so that any pointer argument may alias any other
>   pointer arguments. In this case, the compiler must assume that any
>   accesses through these pointers can alias. This can prevent some
>   optimizations from being made.

This is where the rule is violated:

```
f((int *) &a, &a);
    ^ aliasing to different type (a is 'long')
              ^ passing the same variable with different type
```

The problem is that assuming strict aliasing rules, first and second argument of the function point to another location because these are of different types. That is why author explains:

> Therefore, we can **assume that any long has not changed**.

And in here: `printf("2. v=%ld\n", *l);` a `long` value is dereferenced.

That is why this part (2) is undefined behaviour on both compilers.

Answer (score 3):

Part (2) is not ignored or omitted by the compiler, it is executed and the value of `a` in the caller's scope is modified in some system dependent way, but the compiler can assume that inside function `f()`, modifying an `int` via the pointer `i` does not modify the `long` pointed to by `l`, therefore it can reuse the value read for the first `printf()` as an argument for the second `printf`.

The second compiler seems to generate code that does this while the code generated by the first compiler re-reads the value pointed to by `l`.  Indeed compiler options such as optimisation settings can change this behavior, which is consistent with the C Standard that describes this code as having undefined behavior.

Comment: The fact that different compilers or compiler options with the same compiler have different behavior is *not* a justification to describe code has having **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

The second result is made possible by the fact that the value of `*l` cannot change between (1) and (3).  (The strict aliasing rule ensures that.)

Thus, the program only needs to compute its value once, and the compiler has generated code equivalent to

```
void f(int *i, long *l)
{
  long l2 = *l;
  printf("1. v=%ld\n", l2); /* (1) */
  *i = 11;                  /* (2) */
  printf("2. v=%ld\n", l2); /* (3) */
}
```